# Hide or visible sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I am Table Range from B10:G40 wherein Column B11 onwards shows Sheet Names (IFRS1,2,3 etc) and Column C11:G40 have Yes or No data validations. I need to write a macro to visible or hide Sheets IFRS1,2,3 etc if its Yes in any of the Cell range C11:G40 and hide is its No.

```
If [C11] = "Yes" Then
Sheets("IFRS 1").Visible = True
Else
Sheets("IFRS 1").Visible = False
End If

If [C12] = "Yes" Then
Sheets("IFRS 2").Visible = True
Else
Sheets("IFRS 2").Visible = False
End If

If [C13] = "Yes" Then
Sheets("IFRS 3").Visible = True
Else
Sheets("IFRS 3").Visible = False
End If

If [C14] = "Yes" Then
Sheets("IFRS 5").Visible = True
Else
Sheets("IFRS 5").Visible = False
End If

If [C15] = "Yes" Then
Sheets("IFRS 6").Visible = True
Else
Sheets("IFRS 6").Visible = False
End If

If [C16] = "Yes" Then
Sheets("IFRS 7").Visible = True
Else
Sheets("IFRS 7").Visible = False
End If

If [C17] = "Yes" Then
Sheets("IFRS 13").Visible = True
Else
Sheets("IFRS 13").Visible = False
End If

If [C18] = "Yes" Then
Sheets("IFRS 14").Visible = True
Else
Sheets("IFRS 14").Visible = False
End If

If [C19] = "Yes" Then
Sheets("IFRS 15").Visible = True
Else
Sheets("IFRS 15").Visible = False
End If

If [C20] = "Yes" Then
Sheets("IFRS 16").Visible = True
Else
Sheets("IFRS 16").Visible = False
End If


If [C21] = "Yes" Then
Sheets("IAS 1").Visible = True
Else
Sheets("IAS 1").Visible = False
End If

If [C22] = "Yes" Then
Sheets("IAS 2").Visible = True
Else
Sheets("IAS 2").Visible = False
End If

If [C23] = "Yes" Then
Sheets("IAS 7").Visible = True
Else
Sheets("IAS 7").Visible = False
End If

If [C24] = "Yes" Then
Sheets("IAS 8").Visible = True
Else
Sheets("IAS 8").Visible = False
End If

If [C25] = "Yes" Then
Sheets("IAS 10").Visible = True
Else
Sheets("IAS 10").Visible = False
End If

If [C26] = "Yes" Then
Sheets("IAS 12").Visible = True
Else
Sheets("IAS 12").Visible = False
End If


If [C27] = "Yes" Then
Sheets("IAS 16").Visible = True
Else
Sheets("IAS 16").Visible = False
End If

If [C28] = "Yes" Then
Sheets("IAS 19").Visible = True
Else
Sheets("IAS 19").Visible = False
End If


If [C29] = "Yes" Then
Sheets("IAS 20").Visible = True
Else
Sheets("IAS 20").Visible = False
End If

If [C30] = "Yes" Then
Sheets("IAS 21").Visible = True
Else
Sheets("IAS 21").Visible = False
End If

If [C31] = "Yes" Then
Sheets("IAS 23").Visible = True
Else
Sheets("IAS 23").Visible = False
End If

If [C32] = "Yes" Then
Sheets("IAS 24").Visible = True
Else
Sheets("IAS 24").Visible = False
End If


If [C33] = "Yes" Then
Sheets("IAS 27").Visible = True
Else
Sheets("IAS 27").Visible = False
End If


If [C34] = "Yes" Then
Sheets("IAS 29").Visible = True
Else
Sheets("IAS 29").Visible = False
End If

If [C35] = "Yes" Then
Sheets("IAS 32").Visible = True
Else
Sheets("IAS 32").Visible = False
End If

If [C36] = "Yes" Then
Sheets("IAS 34").Visible = True
Else
Sheets("IAS 34").Visible = False
End If

If [C37] = "Yes" Then
Sheets("IAS 36").Visible = True
Else
Sheets("IAS 36").Visible = False
End If


If [C38] = "Yes" Then
Sheets("IAS 38").Visible = True
Else
Sheets("IAS 38").Visible = False
End If


If [C39] = "Yes" Then
Sheets("IAS 40").Visible = True
Else
Sheets("IAS 40").Visible = False
End If


If [C40] = "Yes" Then
Sheets("IAS 41").Visible = True
Else
Sheets("IAS 41").Visible = False
End If




End Sub
```

Comment: You can replace each `If` block with a one-liner e.g. `Sheets("IFRS 1").Visible = ( [C11] = "Yes" )`  Other than that, is there some specific problem you're having?

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using a loop instead of repeating very similar code:

```vb
Sub HideShowSheets()
    Dim wb As Workbook, x As Long, wsSettings As Worksheet
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsSettings = wb.Worksheets("settings") 'for example
    
    For x = 1 To 41
        wb.Worksheets("IFRS " & x).Visible = (wsSettings.Range("C10").Offset(x).Value = "Yes")
    Next x
End Sub
```